# SQL remove duplicate row

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have next query

```
select No,
       Item,
       Quantity,
       Status
from myTable
```

when execute query I get

[image]

I want to distinct No but with last import quantity, something like this:

[image]

Only to get last data from this table group by No

Comment: what is the actual table structure. Can you share it with us?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Define "last data" Rows in a relational database are ***not*** "sorted". There is no such thing as the "last data" or "last row".

Comment: In yesterdays question you had a `Date` in the table - that would be somewhat useful in sorting the data if that was still relevant - do you have a date in the above data-set?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE (No, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
    SELECT No,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  No
    ORDER BY  No) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM myTable

)
Delete from CTE WHERE DuplicateCount >1
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. You should at least tell us for which DBMS this works. Dev still hasn't told us which DBMS he/she is using (Plus I _think_ he/she doesn't actually want to delete rows, only filter them during retrieval)

Comment: Also `ORDER BY No` will not provide guaranty to get result cause no order column is specified in question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the question
Try this
 `SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY No`

Comment: That is invalid SQL - you can't use `*` together with `GROUP BY` on a single column

Comment: Oh crap, sorry so just go put all columns and do you want erase the other lines

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MS SQL Server**

**Try this**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [No] order by [No] desc) as rn,*
    from myTable
) 

select No,
       Item,
       Quantity,
       Status
from CTE where rn=1;
```